# How do I access the revision-history of an edited CMS page in Kentico?

Tags: content-management-system, kentico, revision-history

I accidently deleted a widget on a CMS page I'm editing with Kentico. Can I access the revision-history in order to get to a previous version of that page that contained the deleted widget?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on Page Versioning [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-and-using-page-versioning) should help.